# How to add href inside node in Gojs?

Tags: javascript, href, gojs

I created a diagram with GoJS.
I need that every node will contain a href.

```
var template = GO(go.Node, "Auto", {
        desiredSize: new go.Size(width, height)
    },
    GO(go.Shape, shapeMap.getValue(shape), new go.Binding("fill", "fill")),
    GO(go.TextBlock, {
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 4
    }, new go.Binding("stroke", "color"), new go.Binding("text", "text")));

var node = {
    key: src,
    color: textColor,
    fill: backgroundColor,
    category: shape,
    text: "www.google.com"
};
```

diagram.model.addNodeData(node);

I tried to insert a Html content.

```
var node = {
    key: src,
    color: textColor,
    fill: backgroundColor,
    category: shape,
    text: <a href='www.google.com'>href</a>
};
```

But it's not working. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TextBlock does not render HTML, but just a string as a block of text.

If you put the URL in your node data, you can declare a [GraphObject.click](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphObject.html#click) event handler that opens a window.

```
GO(go.Node, . . .
  {
    click: function(e, obj) {
        window.open("http://" + encodeURIComponent(obj.part.data.url));
      }
  },
  . . .
  GO(go.TextBlock,
    { textAlign: "center", margin: 4 },
    new go.Binding("stroke", "color"),
    new go.Binding("text", "url"))
  ),
  . . .
)
```

This is for node data such as:

```
{ url: "www.example.com" }
```

You can use a conversion function on the TextBlock.text binding to show a different string than the data.url property value.

It is also demonstrated by the sample at http://gojs.net/latest/samples/euler.html

Comment: This is exactly the solution I did!
I just added the click function to the textBlock, so it's used like a real href.

  GO(go.TextBlock,{font: "7pt serif", click: function(e, obj) {obj.part.data.txtPart2 === '[UMS]' ? window.open("https://" + obj.part.data.key + ":8090") :"";}}),

Anyway, many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add click event to the TextBlock, and in the click function - open new web page.

```
GO(go.Node,...
  GO(go.TextBlock,{textAlign: 'center', click: function(e, obj) {window.open(obj.part.data.url)}}),...);
```